# OrientJS synchronous DB select

Tags: synchronization, orientdb, orientjs

I have a Question about the Javascript OrientJS Driver. The OrientJS Team don't give the opportunity to check if the Database connection with the use() Function was successful. Thats why i want to use a try and catch block. But the use() Function is asynchron so that wont work like it should. Thats why I use a [Framework](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync) to synchronize the Method. Now that is my Code:

```
try {
   databases[dbkey] = orientserver.use.sync({
      name: req.params.database,
      username: username,
      password: password
   });
} catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```

I dont know if the Problem is the Framework or the use() Method but everytime i run this with the right and the wrong login I get this error:

```
{ [OrientDB.ConfigError: Cannot use a database without a name.]
   name: 'OrientDB.ConfigError',
   message: 'Cannot use a database without a name.',
   data: {} }
```

Someone could help me with that?

Comment: Hi @Marvin K Could you post the entire configuration file?

Comment: What do you mean with configuration file? Without the sync Method() the connection works but i cant catch an error